# How to isolate open guest AP from uplinked private AP with dd-wrt

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt

I have two routers, setup like so:

```
            [MODEM]
               |
             [WAN]                 <<<
+-----------------------------+  <<<<
| WRT54GL with stock firmware | <<<< private AP
|         192.168.1.1         | <<<< with WPA
+-----------------------------+  <<<<
             [LAN]                 <<<
               |
               |
               |
             [WAN]                 <<<
+-----------------------------+  <<<<
| WRT54G with dd-wrt v24 mini | <<<< public/guest AP
|         192.168.2.1         | <<<< open access, QoS throttling
+-----------------------------+  <<<<
                                   <<<
```

How do I prevent internal network communication from the guest AP to the private network?  I want to provide guests *only* Internet access and block internal network access to my private computers and devices.

Are there some `iptables` commands I can add to the firewall on the guest router to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found my answer [here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Iptables#Deny_access_to_a_specific_Subnet) and I've added this to `Administration > Commands` and `[Save Firewall]`:

`iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0 -j DROP`

That seems to have blocked access from both ends (guest cannot access private, private cannot access guest), which is just fine.